# Complete example from LaTeX3 intro

Tags: latex3

I don't understand an example from section 6.1 of [expl3-intro.tex](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/blob/master/articles/expl3-intro.tex) from LATEX3 documentation. It is said there:

> Here are two equivalent ways of defining the function `\foo:nn`:
>
> ```
> \cs_set:Npn \foo:nn  #1#2 {(#1)/(#2)}
> \cs_set:cpn {foo:nn} #1#2 {(#1)/(#2)}
> ```
>
> These macros are respectively equivalent to \TeX's
>
> ```
> \long\def\foo:nn
> ```
>
> , and
>
> ```
> \expandafter\long\expandafter\def\csname foo:nn\endcsname
> ```
>
> .
>
> Note the `:nn` suffix to denote that |\foo| takes two arguments.

Given equivalents seem to be reduced rather than complete. **Could somebody provide accurate equivalents of**

```
\cs_set:Npn \foo:nn  #1#2 {(#1)/(#2)}
```

and

```
\cs_set:cpn {foo:nn} #1#2 {(#1)/(#2)}
```

**?**

In particular, I wonder at `\long\def\foo:nn`. Is colon allowed in command names in Plain TeX or LaTeX 2e? Is it assumed here that catcode of `:` has been changed? If so, corresponding commands are suggested to be explicitly added to the above example. And where  is the expanded part of definitions (i.e. `{(#1)/(#2)}`)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In LaTeX3 code blocks, both `:` and `_` are 'letters'. Thus in the demo, the control sequence is `\foo:nn`, including the `:` and the `nn`. As the docs say

```
\cs_set:Npn \foo:nn #1#2 { (#1) / (#2) }
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
\long\def\foo:nn#1#2{(#1)/(#2)}
```

and

```
\cs_set:cpn { foo:nn } #1#2 { (#1) / (#2) }
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
\expandafter\long\expandafter\def\csname foo:nn\endcsname#1#2{(#1)/(#2)}
```

Here, I've taken advantage of fact that spaces are ignored in LaTeX3 code blocks. I've also assumed in the first example that `:` is a 'letter'.

Comment: So, `\long\def` should be prepended with ``\catcode`:=11`` and  ``\catcode`_=11``.

Comment: @Igor Conceptually yes, in the same way as saying that with a lot of LaTeX2e snippets "do not forget `\makeatletter`".

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov I just want to note here that `\ExplSyntaxOn`/`Off` is the expl3 analogue to `\makeatletter`/`other`. Catcode assignments aren't required :) (I say this here because I've *seen* it and they cited this Q.)